# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘listenerCount’) when using NSFWJS in a React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules

i am tryna use nsfwjs in react app, but getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'listenerCount') at node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js (_stream_readable.js:38:9) at __require (chunk-ROME4SDB.js?v=ea232646:11:50) at node_modules/readable-stream/readable.js (readable.js:1:28) at __require (chunk-ROME4SDB.js?v=ea232646:11:50) at node_modules/gif-encoder/lib/GIFEncoder.js (GIFEncoder.js:13:22) at __require (chunk-ROME4SDB.js?v=ea232646:11:50) at node_modules/@nsfw-filter/save-pixels/save-pixels.js (save-pixels.js:3:18) at __require (chunk-ROME4SDB.js?v=ea232646:11:50) at node_modules/@nsfw-filter/gif-frames/gif-frames.js (gif-frames.js:3:18) at __require (chunk-ROME4SDB.js?v=ea232646:11:50)

I followed the official documentation and integrated the library into my application. However, when I try to classify an image using the library, I get a ‘TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘listenerCount’)’ error. The error seems to be coming from the ‘readable-stream’ library, which is a dependency of NSFWJS.

I expected the library to classify the image without any errors, but instead, my application crashes when I try to classify an image. I have tried checking my Node.js version, reinstalling my node modules, and double-checking my usage of NSFWJS, but none of these solutions have resolved the issue. Any help would be appreciated.